# argparse: store_true and int at same time

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse for cli arguments. I want an argument `-t`, to perform a temperature test. I also want to specify the period of temperature measurements.

I want:

`python myscript.py -t` to perform a measurement every 60 seconds,

`python myscript.py -t 30` to perform a measurement every 30 seconds and,

`python myscript.py` not to do the temperature measurement.

Right now I am doing it like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', '--temperature',
                    help='performs temperature test (period in sec)',
                    type=int, default=60, metavar='PERIOD')
```

The problem is that I can not distinguish between `python myscript.py` and `python myscript.py -t`.

It would like to be able to do something like `action='store_true'` and `type=int` at the same time. Is it possible? Any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `const` parameter:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-t', '--temperature',
    help='performs temperature test (period in sec)',
    type=int,
    nargs='?',
    const=60,         # Default value if -t is supplied
    default=None,     # Default value if -t is not supplied
    metavar='PERIOD')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

---

```
% test.py
Namespace(temperature=None)
% test.py -t
Namespace(temperature=60)
% test.py -t 30
Namespace(temperature=30)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. Documentation for const (http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#const) and nargs (http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used argparse before. But recently I saw a presentation on [docopt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXhcPJK5cMc) https://github.com/docopt/docopt that blew me away.

Maybe give that a try?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know it and it might be interesting but for this project I'll stick to argparse.

Comment: You are welcome. I knew my answer really wasn't of much help, but docopt just was on my mind, I had to mention it.